# Use lookup table to create new raster layer based on values in multi-layer SpatRaster using R terra

Tags: r, terra, land-classification

I am doing an ecosystem classification project where I have 3 raster layers that each correspond to different ecological classes with different numbers of categories. I want to take the unique combinations of values from the 3 raster layers and manually create a lookup table in order to make a new raster layer (e.g., if layer 1 = 1, layer 2 = 1, and layer 3 = 1, then layer 4 = "forest").

I know how to do all of the parts except creating the final raster layer from the lookup table. Because there will be dozens of unique combinations, I would like to supply a dataframe instead of coding the combinations individually.

I'm assuming there's a straightforward way to do this, but I'm somewhat new to geospatial analysis and I couldn't find a similar solution online.

Here's a simple reproducible example:

EDIT:

I have edited the question as I've worked through my real data, and have found that the `subst()` solution does not work if there is more than one categorical layer:

`Error: [subst] you can only use 'subst' with categorical layers if x has a single layer`

```
library(terra)

# create 3 raster layers
r1 <- rast(matrix(1:5, 10, 10))
r2 <- rast(matrix(1:4, 10, 10))
r3 <- rast(matrix(1:8, 10, 10)) 
r4 <- rast(matrix(1:8, 10, 10)) 

# convert to categorical rasters
cats.r1 <- data.frame(id=1:5, smr = c("A",
                                       "B",
                                       "C",
                                       "D",
                                       "E"))

levels(r1) <- cats.r1

cats.r2 <- data.frame(id=1:4, smr = c("012",
                                       "34",
                                       "56",
                                       "78W"))
levels(r2) <- cats.r2

cats.r3 <- data.frame(1:8, cover = c("broadleaf_forest",
                                             "broadleaf_shrub",
                                             "conifer_forest",
                                             "conifer_shrub",
                                             "herb_meadow",
                                             "non_sparse_veg",
                                             "tundra_grassland_heath",
                                             "glacier"))
levels(r3) <- cats.r3

cats.r4 <- data.frame(1:8, cover = c("ESSFmc",
                                     "ESSFmcw",
                                     "ESSFmv3",
                                     "ESSFmv4",
                                     "SWBmk",
                                     "SBSmc2",
                                     "BWBSdk",
                                     "ESSFmcp"))

levels(r4) <- cats.r4

# combine into single spatraster
r <- c(r1, r2, r3, r4)

# name classification layers
names(r) <- c("nutrients", "moisture", "landcover", "BGC")

# find unique combinations of values
lookup <- unique(r)
```

```
> print(lookup)
   nutrients moisture              landcover     BGC
1          A      012       broadleaf_forest  ESSFmc
2          A      012            herb_meadow   SWBmk
3          A       34        broadleaf_shrub ESSFmcw
4          A       34         non_sparse_veg  SBSmc2
5          A       56         conifer_forest ESSFmv3
6          A       56 tundra_grassland_heath  BWBSdk
7          A      78W          conifer_shrub ESSFmv4
8          A      78W                glacier ESSFmcp
9          B      012       broadleaf_forest  ESSFmc
10         B      012            herb_meadow   SWBmk
11         B       34        broadleaf_shrub ESSFmcw
12         B       34         non_sparse_veg  SBSmc2
13         B       56         conifer_forest ESSFmv3
14         B       56 tundra_grassland_heath  BWBSdk
15         B      78W          conifer_shrub ESSFmv4
16         B      78W                glacier ESSFmcp
17         C      012       broadleaf_forest  ESSFmc
18         C      012            herb_meadow   SWBmk
19         C       34        broadleaf_shrub ESSFmcw
20         C       34         non_sparse_veg  SBSmc2
21         C       56         conifer_forest ESSFmv3
22         C       56 tundra_grassland_heath  BWBSdk
23         C      78W          conifer_shrub ESSFmv4
24         C      78W                glacier ESSFmcp
25         D      012       broadleaf_forest  ESSFmc
26         D      012            herb_meadow   SWBmk
27         D       34        broadleaf_shrub ESSFmcw
28         D       34         non_sparse_veg  SBSmc2
29         D       56         conifer_forest ESSFmv3
30         D       56 tundra_grassland_heath  BWBSdk
31         D      78W          conifer_shrub ESSFmv4
32         D      78W                glacier ESSFmcp
33         E      012       broadleaf_forest  ESSFmc
34         E      012            herb_meadow   SWBmk
35         E       34        broadleaf_shrub ESSFmcw
36         E       34         non_sparse_veg  SBSmc2
37         E       56         conifer_forest ESSFmv3
38         E       56 tundra_grassland_heath  BWBSdk
39         E      78W          conifer_shrub ESSFmv4
40         E      78W                glacier ESSFmcp
```

When I try to use the unique combinations in the lookup table to create a new layer based on the values in `lookup$ecosystem`, I get this error:

```
# Assign final ecosystem class depending on combination of 4 values
# (we will do this manually in excel and import into R)
lookup$ecosystem <- c(rep("forest",5),
                      rep("shrub",5),
                      rep("grassland",5),
                      rep("tundra",5),
                      rep("heath", 5),
                      rep("bare_ground", 5),
                      rep("glacier", 5),
                      rep("wetland", 5))

> z <- subst(r, lookup[ ,1:4], as.factor(lookup[ ,5]))
Error: [subst] you can only use 'subst' with categorical layers if x has a single layer
```

Is there a way to do this with categorical rasters, or do I need to convert from categorical back to integer? I am using the latest development version of 'terra' (1.7.69).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that `terra::subst()` does no work with multiple categorial layers, so you need to convert the layers to numeric. That also means that you need to carefully construct a numeric lookup table, so that the factor levels are the same as in the original raster. The code below assumes that you have constructed your raster and the lookup as per your example and then converts everything to numeric:

```r
lev <- levels(r)     # we get the original factor levels of the raster
lookup_num <- lookup # dummy for subst() to be filled with numerics

# loop over the layers, sets the levels as in the raster and converts to numeric

lookup_num[] <- lapply(1:nlyr(r), function(i) {
    as.numeric(factor(lookup[ ,i], levels = lev[[i]][,2]))
    })

# we can now apply subst on a numeric version of r
# we use the original `ecosystem` column to get a categorial raster
z <- subst(as.numeric(r), lookup_num[ ,1:4], lookup[ ,5])
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work well! The only issue is that the new raster is stored as integers, but they don't seem to be in the same order as listed. Does as.factor() coerce the order of the categories to alphabetical? Do you know of a way to follow through (or add labels) to confirm?

For example, values 1/1/1 results in '2' in the new raster, even though 'forest' comes first in the lookup table...

Comment: Yes, its a factor now so you need to learn the levels and set them on the new raster too. You can get the levels e.g. via `m <- data.frame(values = 1:8, ecosystem = levels(as.factor(lookup[ ,4])))` then set `levels(r) <- m`.

Comment: With terra 1.7-65 setting the levels are set automatically, and you can also use the character values as argument "to":  `z <- subst(r, lookup[ ,1:3], lookup[ ,4])`

Comment: Hello, I have edited my question as the provided solution does not work with multiple categorical raster layers. Do you know of a workaround for this?

Comment: The error message tells you what to do: You cannot provide a multi-layer raster to `subst()` with multiple categorical layers. So you'll have to convert your raster to numeric (`as.numeric(r)`), preferably before constructing the lookup tabel.

Comment: Edited the answer to show the conversion.

Comment: Thank you @darius.goergen, this is exactly what I needed! Sending an invisible upvote because I do not have enough reputation to do a real one!